# Is AfxBeginThread safe?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, mfc

According to [this webpage](http://members.cox.net/doug_web/threads.htm):

> To safely use CWinThread, you must
>   start the thread suspended and set the
>   CWinThread object's m_bAutoDelete
>   member to false or DuplicateHandle a
>   copy of its m_hThread member

Does this mean that the [AfxBeginThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) function is unsafe to use as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked seems pretty clear - you can set the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag in the call to `AfxBeginThread` and set the `m_bAutoDelete` member before calling `CWinThread::ResumeThread`, along with any other required initialization. If you do that then it should be perfectly safe.